# Does .net run on Unix and Mac?

Tags: .net, windows, macos, unix

Quoting the [documentation of Path.DirectorySeparatorChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar)

> The value of this field is a slash ("/") on Unix, and a backslash ("\") on the Windows and Macintosh operating systems.

Did MS, as that text is there since at least [.net 1.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), write this in anticipation of a future port or of the creation of (something like) Mono? Or can I run .net on a non-MS OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to read about .NET's history and its close relationship with Java, so as to know of why such designs exist in the API.

Microsoft shiped Java, and even extended its feature set by developing J++. But SUN bans such attempts and that's why .NET was born. Thus, .NET is very similar to Java, and its API generally speaking is portable.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_J%2B%2B

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework

However, Microsoft never releases .NET Framework for any other platforms except Windows, which is an obvious strategy to promote Windows. The only exception so far is a product called Silverlight for Mac, which ports a lite version of .NET Framework to OS X,

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/981760

Mono and Xamarin.iOS/Android/Mac is probably not what Microsoft expected around 2000, but now even Microsoft uses such products, and welcome the innovations from the community.

IMHO, .NET is only a brand for CLR on Windows. Mono and Xamarin.* can be seen as the brands for CLR on other platforms. So if you rephrase your last question to "can I run a CLR based application on a non-MS OS", I would like to answer that "yes, it is".

Comment: Interesting - Silverlight for Mac. I bet in that case `DirectorySeparatorChar` will be the forward slash, though, since OS X...

Comment: @EugeneBeresovksy I don't have a Mac to test, but I believe it should be forward slash. Microsoft did not expect Mac OS becomes obsolete some day, but we do see it happens :)

Comment: .NET Core exists on Unix: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux

Comment: @mirik note that the discussion was in 2013, so .NET Core didn’t even exist.